# Как вывести количество товаров на странице в фильтре битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как вывести количество товаров на странице в битрикс? 
К примеру если мы находимся в catalog/odejda и там у нас 10 товаров.
А если мы находимся в catalog/djinsi то там у нас 23 товара.

Мне нужно узнать количество в catalog.smart.filter что бы не выводить фильтр если на странице менее 5 товаров.

Наверное нужно делать что то с CIBlockSection::GetList и SelectedRowsCount(), но мне не хватает знаний для этого.

Comment: Для этого вовсе не нужно лезть в базу и дергать ее по пустякам. Вам нужно всего-навсего получить количество элементов в массиве `$arResult`, которое выводит компонент в данный момент на странице. считать элементы массива в разы быстрее. еще можно через js посчитать количество `<div >` которые выводят товары. но через $arResult надежнее всего как мне кажется.

Comment: @НиколайСарры К сожалению таким образом вы не посчитаете если выводятся не все из-за постраничной навигации.

Comment: @Mihanik71 согласен, забыл про постраничку (скорее всего потому что в вопросе про нее не сказано), если так то да - через методы инфоблоков.

Answer (score 2):

Компонент smart.filter в массив который указан в настройка компонента (по умолчанию это arrFilter) собирает массив в котором находятся параметры для фильтрации. Далее этот массив попадает в компонент catalog.section а в нём уже делает getList, в котором получается массив товаров для вывода с учётом остальных параметров. Поэтому если мы выполним getList с фильтром указанным в arrFilter, то получим список товаров по заданноve фильтру. А если мы передадим в параметре arGroupBy пустой массив, то функция вернёт количество товаров, которое мы и искали.

Итоговый код для комплексного компонента:

```
$filter = array(
    "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
    "SECTION_ID" => $sectionId // если есть
);
global $arrFilter;
$filter = array_merge($filter, $arrFilter);

$cnt = CIBlockElement::GetList(
    array(),
    array($filter),
    array(),
    false,
    array('ID', 'NAME')
);
```